# Align images inside a horizontal list in a specific way

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

Automatically align images inside horizontal list with first element to left aligned, last element to be right aligned and middle images to be equally aligned in between.

I have a horizontal list of 3 images and I want the images to be aligned as described above. Sample HTML is given here
http://jsfiddle.net/er3t4u8v/1/

```
<div id="nav">
<div class="header-row">
     <div class="title">Widget Title</div>
     <div class="action">See more</div>
</div>
<ul>
    <li><img src="images/kranznav.png" alt="kranz" /><a href="index.php">COM</a></li>
    <li><img src="images/thumbnav.png" alt="thumb" /><a href="index.php">SCO</a></li>
    <li><img src="images/bagnav.png" alt="bag" /><a href="index.php">SHO</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="clear">
</div>

#nav {
    background:#ffffff;
    width:100%;
    margin-top:2em;  
    margin-left: 2rem;
    margin-right: 5rem;
}

#nav .header-row {
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 2.32rem;
    padding-top: .56rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.56rem;
}
#nav .title {
    font-size: .88rem !important;
    float: left;
}
#nav .action {
    float: right;
    font-size: .64rem;
    padding-right: 5rem;
}
#nav ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#nav li {
    display:inline;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#nav li:first-child{
    float:left;
    padding-left: 0;
}

#nav li:last-child{
    float:right;
    padding-right:5rem;
}

#nav a {
    display:block;
    width:20%;
    margin-right:0% auto;
    padding-left:0% auto;
    color:#5E09CB;
    text-decoration:none;

}
```

I'm struggling to get the middle image to align to the center. I already tried margin: 0 auto, but it doesn't seem to work without specifying the width and I can't hard code the width in this case, as it can vary based on layout and resolution.

So I tried setting the width dynamically (through java script) and the middle element didn't centered in the available space.

Comment: hi @Viz  i have created two demo for you please check it .

Comment: Thanks Rohit for looking into it. Will check them also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if try to use display: inline-block and text-align: justify?

```
<div id="nav">
<div class="header-row">
     <div class="title">Widget Title</div>
     <div class="action">See more</div>
</div>
<ul>
    <li><img src="images/kranznav.png" alt="kranz" /><a href="index.php">COM</a></li>
    <li><img src="images/thumbnav.png" alt="thumb" /><a href="index.php">SCO</a></li>
    <li><img src="images/bagnav.png" alt="bag" /><a href="index.php">SHO</a></li>

</ul>
</div>
<div class="clear">
```

CSS

```
 #nav {
        background:#cccccc;
        margin-top:2em;  
        margin-left: 2rem;
        margin-right: 5rem;
    }

    #nav .header-row {
        vertical-align: middle;
        height: 2.32rem;
        padding-top: .56rem;
        padding-bottom: 0.56rem;
    }
    #nav .title {
        font-size: .88rem !important;
        float: left;
    }
    #nav .action {
        float: right;
        font-size: .64rem;
        padding-right: 5rem;
    }
    #nav ul {
        list-style-type:none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: justify;
        border: solid 1px red;
        width: 100%;
    }
    #nav li {
        display:inline-block;
        border: solid 1px black;
      }

    #nav ul:after {
        content: "";
        width: 100%;
        display: inline-block;
        }



    #nav a {

        text-decoration:none;

    }
```

Fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/er3t4u8v/4/

Answer (score 0):

HI @VIz now you can used to `table` **property** as like this

now define your `ul` tag `display` `table` **property**

and you  `li` tag `display` `table-cell` **property**

**Example**

```
#nav ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}
#nav li {
    display:table-cell;
    text-align: center;
}


#nav a {
    display:block;
    color:#5E09CB;
    text-decoration:none;

}
```

**Demo**

```css
#nav {
    background:#ffffff;
    margin-top:2em;  
    margin-left: 2rem;
    margin-right: 5rem;
}

#nav .header-row {
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 2.32rem;
    padding-top: .56rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.56rem;
}
#nav .title {
    font-size: .88rem !important;
    float: left;
}
#nav .action {
    float: right;
    font-size: .64rem;
    padding-right: 5rem;
}
#nav ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}
#nav li {
    display:table-cell;
    text-align: center;
}


#nav a {
    display:block;
    color:#5E09CB;
    text-decoration:none;

}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
<div class="header-row">
     <div class="title">Widget Title</div>
     <div class="action">See more</div>
</div>
<ul>
    <li><img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/59282562ee769ff6143e7e5024c4b115?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" alt="kranz" /><a href="index.php">COM</a></li>
    <li><img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/59282562ee769ff6143e7e5024c4b115?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" alt="thumb" /><a href="index.php">SCO</a></li>
    <li><img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/59282562ee769ff6143e7e5024c4b115?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" alt="bag" /><a href="index.php">SHO</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="clear">
</div>
```

=======================================

## Second Option

Now used to this

```
#nav ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display:block;font-size:0;
}
#nav li:first-child{
    text-align:left;
}
#nav li:last-child{
    text-align:right;
}
#nav li {
    display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;
    width:33.33%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size:12px;
}
```

**[Demo Jsfiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitmalikazad/er3t4u8v/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use "[float](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp)" properly.

```css
img {
  width: 120px;
}

li {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
<div class="header-row">
     <div class="title">Widget Title</div>
     <div class="action">See more</div>
</div>
<ul>
    <li><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/static.carthrottle.com/workspace/uploads/comments/fan-54ce422962b1a.jpg" alt="kranz" /><a href="index.php">COM</a></li>
    <li><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/static.carthrottle.com/workspace/uploads/comments/fan-54ce422962b1a.jpg" alt="thumb" /><a href="index.php">SCO</a></li>
    <li><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/static.carthrottle.com/workspace/uploads/comments/fan-54ce422962b1a.jpg" alt="bag" /><a href="index.php">SHO</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="clear">
</div>
```

It's a good practice to create a class which I usually call "clearboy". It should look like this:

```
.clearboy {
 clear: both;
}
```

You are able to place a `<div class="clearboy"/>` beneath every floating element, so that the floating behaves "normal" again. I assume that your `<div class="clear">` is meant to do so.

You also may find [this](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_float5) example useful.

Further reading:

- http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float

The full code:

```css
img {
  width: 120px;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

#nav {
    background:#ffffff;
    width:100%;
    margin-top:2em;  
    margin-left: 2rem;
    margin-right: 5rem;
}

#nav .header-row {
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 2.32rem;
    padding-top: .56rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.56rem;
}
#nav .title {
    font-size: .88rem !important;
    float: left;
}
#nav .action {
    float: right;
    font-size: .64rem;
    padding-right: 5rem;
}
#nav ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#nav li {
    display:inline;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#nav a {
    display:block;
    width:20%;
    margin-right:0% auto;
    padding-left:0% auto;
    color:#5E09CB;
    text-decoration:none;

}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
    <div class="header-row">
         <div class="title">Widget Title</div>
         <div class="action">See more</div>
    </div>
    <ul>
        <li><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/static.carthrottle.com/workspace/uploads/comments/fan-54ce422962b1a.jpg" alt="kranz" /><a href="index.php">COM</a></li>
        <li><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/static.carthrottle.com/workspace/uploads/comments/fan-54ce422962b1a.jpg" alt="thumb" /><a href="index.php">SCO</a></li>
        <li><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/static.carthrottle.com/workspace/uploads/comments/fan-54ce422962b1a.jpg" alt="bag" /><a href="index.php">SHO</a></li>
    </ul>
```

If you exclusively want to glue the right image to the right border of the window you can do it like this:

```css
img {
  width: 120px;
}

li {
  display: block;
}

#nav {
    background:#ffffff;
    width:100%;
    margin-top:2em;  
    margin-left: 2rem;
    margin-right: 5rem;
}

#nav .header-row {
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 2.32rem;
    padding-top: .56rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.56rem;
}
#nav .title {
    font-size: .88rem !important;
    float: left;
}
#nav .action {
    float: right;
    font-size: .64rem;
    padding-right: 5rem;
}
#nav ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#nav li {
    display:inline;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#nav a {
    display:block;
    width:20%;
    margin-right:0% auto;
    padding-left:0% auto;
    color:#5E09CB;
    text-decoration:none;

}

li:first-child {
  margin-left:0;
  margin-right:auto;
  width: 33%;
}

li:first-child img {
  float: left;
}

li:nth-child(2) {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 33%
}

li:last-child {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 0;
  width: 33%;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
    <div class="header-row">
         <div class="title">Widget Title</div>
         <div class="action">See more</div>
    </div>
    <ul>
        <li><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/static.carthrottle.com/workspace/uploads/comments/fan-54ce422962b1a.jpg" alt="kranz" /><a href="index.php">COM</a></li>
        <li><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/static.carthrottle.com/workspace/uploads/comments/fan-54ce422962b1a.jpg" alt="thumb" /><a href="index.php">SCO</a></li>
        <li><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/static.carthrottle.com/workspace/uploads/comments/fan-54ce422962b1a.jpg" alt="bag" /><a href="index.php">SHO</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Please notice the following CSS lines:

```
li:first-child {
  margin-left:0;
  margin-right:auto;
  width: 33%;
}

li:first-child img {
  float: left;
}

li:nth-child(2) {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 33%
}

li:last-child {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 0;
  width: 33%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this-

```css
 #nav {
    background:#ffffff;
    /*width:100%;*/
    margin-top:2em;  
    margin-left: 2rem;
    margin-right: 5rem;

}
#nav li img{
 display: block;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

#nav .header-row {
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 2.32rem;
    padding-top: .56rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.56rem;
}
#nav .title {
    font-size: .88rem !important;
    float: left;
}
#nav .action {
    float: right;
    font-size: .64rem;
    /*padding-right: 5rem;*/
}
#nav ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#nav li {
    display:inline;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    width: 80%;
}

#nav li:first-child{
    float:left;
    padding-left: 0;
    width: 10%;
}

#nav li:last-child{
    float:right;
    /*padding-right:5rem;*/
    width: 10%;
}

#nav a {
    display:block;
    /*width:20%;*/
    margin-right:0% auto;
    padding-left:0% auto;
    color:#5E09CB;
    text-decoration:none;

}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
 <div class="header-row">
      <div class="title">Widget Title</div>
      <div class="action">See more</div>
 </div>
 <ul>
     <li><img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRcirYtkcgdoZeg7LaZ_lub1cdv0I9FgYcwkZVSkY_c6Vs4gbZ0GOvsrQ" alt="kranz" /><a href="index.php">COM</a></li>
     <li><img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRcirYtkcgdoZeg7LaZ_lub1cdv0I9FgYcwkZVSkY_c6Vs4gbZ0GOvsrQ" alt="thumb" /><a href="index.php">SCO</a></li>
     <li><img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRcirYtkcgdoZeg7LaZ_lub1cdv0I9FgYcwkZVSkY_c6Vs4gbZ0GOvsrQ" alt="bag" /><a href="index.php">SHO</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
 <div class="clear"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be use a flexbox? The example below can be tweaked as per need! :)

http://codepen.io/praveenpuglia/pen/qdgaVa

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.left,
.center,
.right {
  height: 200px;
  background: #bada55;
}
.left,
.right {
  width: 20%;
  margin: 20px;
}
.center {
  background: #ff0066;
  -webkit-align-self: center;
  -ms-flex-item-align: center;
  align-self: center;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="center"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```